# Flask, SQLAlchemy: How to make column autoincrement

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm defining a model like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last = db.Column(db.String(64))
    dob = db.Column(db.Date)
    street_addr1 = db.Column(db.String(64))
    street_addr2 = db.Column(db.String(64))
    city = db.Column(db.String(64))
    state = db.Column(db.String(2))
    zip = db.Column(db.String(9))
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum('M', 'F'))
    home_box = db.Column(db.String(32))
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

views.py:

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user = User()
        user.username = form.username.data
        user.first = form.first_name.data
        user.last = form.last_name.data
        user.city = form.city.data
        user.dob = form.dob.data
        user.gender = form.gender.data
        user.home_box = form.home_box.data
        user.state = form.state.data
        user.street_addr1 = form.street_addr1.data
        user.street_addr2 = form.street_addr2.data
        user.zip = form.zip.data
        user.password = form.password.data
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit
```

Right now, inserts are failing because the id is not set:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) constraint failed 'INSERT INTO users  (first, last, dob, street_addr1, street_addr2, city, state, zip, gender, home_box, username, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' ('Nate', 'Reed', '1980-11-11', '', '', '', '', '', 'male', '', 'natereed', 'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$N8JHXEDU$24a7724ae9edda81a73e6b92d23aa576ad8284aa')
```

How do I make id autoincrement? My understanding is it has to be done at the table (not column) level. How do I do this in the code above?

Comment: what do you mean "inserts are failing because id is not set". can you share the exact error ? You do not need to auto-increment manually necessarily and hence I am assuming that you have some other issue

Comment: Hi codegeek, it's failing with IntegrityError. Updated my post with error message.

Comment: can you post the entire Model code and also the view where you are inserting ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem was I was trying to insert a value for gender that is not valid. It's an enum with values 'M' or 'F'.

It would be nice if the form could just be generated from the model, as that would eliminate the potential for this error. Any pointers on doing that with Flask?